# how to concatenate cuurent array data with previous array data in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, concatenation

I am doing server side pagination in my MERN project. Suppose I get 100 products from Database and I want to show only 30 products, 10 products per page. and I want that when user want to visit 4rth page I make another call to api to get next 30 products and previous 30 should not overridden. So I need to concatenate current array data with previous data. How can I do this?

Here is my code:
calling api function using `useQuery` and send `offset` and `postsPerPage(limit)` and `jwttoken` as arguments:

```js
 let { isFetching: isFetchingPage, refetch: fetchPage } = useQuery(
    ["pages", user],
    async (user) => {
     
      return await getProductsPage(
        user?.queryKey[1]?.jwtToken,
        offset,
        postsPerPage,
      );
    },
    {
      enabled: false,
      staleTime: 10000,
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        setProduct(data?.data?.data);
      },
    }
  );
```

Get data from API

```js
  export const getProductsPage = async (token, offset, limit,)=>{
        
        
        {
            const data = await axios.get(`getMarketPlace`,
            {
                params:{
                    details:false, offset:offset, limit:limit
                },
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    Authorization:token,
                    
                }
            })
            return data
        }
    }
```

it works perfectly the only thing I want is that to concatenate currentData with previous data.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the spread operator `…`.

```
onSuccess: (data) => {
  const newData = data?.data?.data
  if (!newData) return // return if data not valid
  setProduct([…product, …newData]) // concatenate arrays
}
```

More about the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: it concatenates correctly but api data nevers end?? e.g when all products shown that are fetched from database it shows more products from start . so pagination never ends

Answer (score 0):

```
SetState((oldState) => [...oldState, ...newData])
```